Why confidence interval for proportion uses z instead of t score?
The confidence interval (Wald interval) for the parameter $p$ of a binomial distribution is computed from the approximation by a Normal distribution:
$$ \ p ~~ \approx ~~ \hat p \pm \frac{\; z_\alpha\ }{\ \sqrt{n\; }\ }\ \sqrt{ \hat p\ \left(1 - \hat p \right)\ }\ $$
(source)
Naturally, the sample standard deviation above uses sample/observed data ($\hat{p}$), since the original value is not known. Recall that the population st. dev. of a Binomial is $np(1-p)$.
I wonder why the $z$ score is used instead of a $t$ score. In the analogue case for the population mean $\mu$, the confidence intervals for the case of known $\sigma$ is:
$$ \ \mu ~~ \approx ~~  \bar{x} \pm \frac{\; z_\alpha\ }{\ \sqrt{n\; }\ }\ \sigma $$
whereas for the case of unknown is:
$$ \ \mu ~~ \approx ~~  \bar{x} \pm \frac{\; t_\alpha\ }{\ \sqrt{n\; }\ }\ S $$
where $S$ is sample st. dev.
In the binomial case, we use the sample st. dev, so I cannot understand why $z$ is used instead of $t$. Is this an approximation because $n$ is assumed large enough?
PD: this related question says Student is not appropriate but explanation is not clear, and unclear whether true or not.

in short: the t distribution on the sample mean assumes that your data come from a normal distribution, and corrects for the funkyness introduced by estimating the variance in such a context. Because binomial data are quite clearly non-normal, being only either 0 or 1, the justification for using a t-distribution is absent. (and besides: you're not even estimating a variance!).

(PS: not sure what you mean when you say "In the binomial case, we use the sample st. dev"; in your first equation you have an estimate for the standard deviation of the data which does not depend on the sample st. dev. )

The Wald interval is computed in the context of MLE which assumes the sample size is so large that the usual asymptotic analysis justifies the use of this method.  For small $n,$ all bets are off.  That's why you ought to be using better CI procedures, such as the Clopper-Pearson.
